# How to hide button value in url?

Tags: html

This is my search form:

```
   <form action="" method="get" name="search">
   <input name="s" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo $_GET["s"]; ?>" />
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
   </form>
```

When someone clicks the search button the url in browser's address bar is something like this:

> http://example.com/?s=someting&submit=Search

How can I change it so that it only displays:

> http://example.com/?s=someting

Hope I'm clear...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove name="submit" from the `<input type="submit">` button

Answer (score 0):

Like " Ivar Bonsaksen " said you have to remove the "name" attribute because `the value of every tag in the Form tag with a name attribute` will be sent to the server and will appear in the URL.

P.S:
You can use the POST method instead of GET to hide all the variables and values.